# Biblatex (bath) and removing punctuation from the reference list

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib, punctuation

I am using the style Bath with Biblatex, however I wish to remove a comma from way references are listed. For now my references show:

[image]

However my university requires:

> ORTON, C. & HUGHES, M. 2013. *Pottery in Archaeology*, ...

So I want to remove the comma between the names and the date.
For now, my reference packages and such look like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=bath,backend=biber,maxcitenames=1,natbib=true,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace} %PRBL TO SOLVE when \citaltp
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon} %\addcolon\space if 
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\AtBeginBibliography{\let\mkbibnamefamily\textsc} %Last name in Upper Case in reference list
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}


As said... \citep[]{orton_pottery_2013}



\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and with references.bib

```
@book{orton_pottery_2013,
    series = {Cambridge {Manuals} in {Archaeology}},
    title = {Pottery in {Archaeology}},
    isbn = {978-1-107-00874-8},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    author = {Orton, C. and Hughes, M.},
    year = {2013},
    lccn = {2012037613},}
```

Has anyone any idea how that can be done easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\DeclareDelimFormat` command is context-sensitive. You have to add the `bib` option.

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite,bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly